# No Init Scripts available after installing Mongodb package on Bash on Windows

Tags: systemd, mongodb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The expected behaviour after installing Mongodb on Ubuntu is an init script to be added to the init.d directory, allowing you to start and stop the service. However, the directory `/etc/init.d` does not exist and there is no scripts.

Bash on Windows is using version 14.04 and Mongodb documentation said this version does not use systemd.

I took it upon myself to add the `init.d` directory and create the mongod init script, but I am not sure if this is best practice? Also, I may experience it again when installing other packages.

Would appreciate your help and support. Thank you.

Comment: Upstart scripts are in `/etc/init` and not in `/etc/init.d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note - Bash/Ubuntu/WSL in Win10AU doesn't currently use initd - it uses a custom simplified init that avoids many of the steps normally required when initializing a Linux OS/Kernel, some of which are unnecessary because its resting atop an already initialized Windows kernel.

Also, note that when you close your last bash console, any running bash processes are torn-down.

We're working on improving this in a future release, but for now, I recommend creating a bash script that starts-up the daemons etc., that you need, which you run manually after you've started a new Bash session.